# Print arguments of a function in R

Tags: r, function, parameters, arguments

Is it possible to print the arguments of a function?

Example, this is my function:

```
my_function <- function(argument_1, argument_2){
            my_equation <- argument_1 + argument_2
            return(my_equation)
}
```

And i run it with this code:

```
my_save <- my_function(argument_1=1, argument_2=123)
```

Is it possible to write something like this `GET.MY.FUNCTION.PARAMETERS(my_save)` which would return a vector or list with `1, 123`

Comment: you can also look into `match.call` if the arguments change inside the function `m <- match.call(); m$argument_1` allows you to index any of the arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do this is to pass the arguments back in `return` as part of a list:

```
my_function <- function(argument_1, argument_2){
        my_equation <- argument_1 + argument_2
        return(list(eqn = my_equation, arg1 = argument_1, arg2 = argument_2))
}
```

So that you can assign an output:

```
results <- my_function(foo1, foo2)
```

and then strip the information you need:

```
eqn <- results$eqn
args <- with(results, c(arg1, arg2))
print(args)
```